# Understanding Type Casting in inheritence

Tags: java

I am preparing for java certification and unable to find any concept or logic behind this.
Can anyone help me understanding the concept of multiple typecasting. I can understand the one level of type casting but I am not getting any information for these conversions.
Here is the sample I am trying to understand.

```
interface I{
}
class A implements I{
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B{
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

Now option 1 don't have any error at compile time or runtime, while 2nd option is having error. I run it in eclipse but unable to understand the logic behind this.

```
1.  a = (B)(I)b;
2.  b = (B)(I)a;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking - these are just two type casts, done one after the other. If you understand what `x + y` then you should understand what `x + y + z` means, because it's just the same thing done twice; what's different about this?

Comment: Your middle paragraph is a bit messy, rephrasing it might help getting an answer. Might also help to explain what you mean by "correct", as in the industry both would be considered very much incorrect (I believe it's the first time in my life I've seen a double-cast, and I've had to read a lot of crappy code through my job).

Comment: I assume it's "which will not raise an error", and in that case I suggest you run the code to see for yourself, then if you can't understand why it is as it is, rewording your question as "Why does X work but not Y?" might get better reception

Comment: I rephrased it Aaron. And Kaya I understand these are 2 type casts but can you tell me why 1st is correct and 2nd is incorrect.

Comment: There is no reason to include the caste to `I`, casting doesn't change anything about the object. Your number 2 is equivalent to `B b = (B)a;`

Comment: ``B b = (B)a;`` doesn't work because you can't expand an A to a B.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I'll see if I can help.

So you have your interface I and classes A, B and C.

You can now do things like these:

```
I i1 = new A();
I i2 = new B();
I i3 = new C();
```

This is possible because, by inheritance, all the classes A, B and C implement I.

You can also do

```
A a1 = new B();
A a2 = new C();
```

for almost the same reason (difference being they are extending A rather than implementing an interface).

You probably guessed by now that you can also do

```
B b1 = new C();
```

What you *can't* do is something like

```
B b = new A(); // Type error
C c = new B(); // Type error
B b2 = (B)new A(); // ClassCastException
```

This is not possible since the type A does not extend from B.

In general you don't need to explicitly type cast in these cases.

```
I i = (I)new A(); // <- not necessary
```

It can be necessary in the opposite direction however:

```
I i = new B();
B b = (B)i; // <- cast is needed.
```

This works if and only if i is actually of type B (or C). If the object i is not of type B or a type that extends from B you will get ClassCastException.

**Now for your question**

Both your two options are a bit strange. Double casting is not something you would normally do. the cast to I is unnecessary.

With that said, 1) will work and 2) will not. Your object b cannot be assigned a because A does not extend from B.

**Edit**

To be clear, when you instantiate an object, for example

```
A a = new A();
```

The actual object (I'm going to call it o) is an instance of class A. You also have an object reference called 'a' which is typed as A which refers to the object o.

When you assign other object references, the type of the actual object doesn't change. When assigning a reference, the type of the object must be the same type as the reference or of a type that inherits from the referred type.

For example, you can assign a reference of type I:

```
I i = a;
```

This assigns the reference i to the same object that a refers to which is the object o. Note that o is still of type A.

```
   System.out.println(i instanceof A);
```

will print
`true`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I understand the one level cast. I have rephrased the question . can you tell me why 1st option is correct and 2nd is not.

Comment: Case 1 is fine because B is a child class of A. The casting completely unnecessary though. Case 2 does not work because A is not a child class of B. You can only cast to a type higher up in the hierarchy.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for pointing it out. I will update the answer.